# COM Interop com CLient e Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, dll

Olá, tenho uma DLL para criptografar dados. Necessito utilizar o Component Object Model(COM) Interop para conseguir comunicar duas aplicações e ambas trafegarem os dados criptografados por meio desta DLL.
Pesquisando, encontrei exemplos de integração como integrar com o Microsoft Office, mas não com outra aplicação.

Como solicitado, segue o exemplo que encontrei no site da Microsoft( e em cursos do DevMedia)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Account
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public double Balance { get; set; }
}


var bankAccounts = new List<Account> 
{
new Account 
{
    ID = 345,
    Balance = 541.27
},
new Account 
{
    ID = 123,
    Balance = -127.44
}
};


void DisplayInExcel(IEnumerable<Account> accounts,
       Action<Account, Excel.Range> DisplayFunc)
{
var excelApp = this.Application;
// Add a new Excel workbook.
excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
excelApp.Visible = true;
excelApp.Range["A1"].Value = "ID";
excelApp.Range["B1"].Value = "Balance";
excelApp.Range["A2"].Select();

foreach (var ac in accounts)
{
    DisplayFunc(ac, excelApp.ActiveCell);
    excelApp.ActiveCell.Offset[1, 0].Select();
}
// Copy the results to the Clipboard.
excelApp.Range["A1:B3"].Copy();

excelApp.Columns[1].AutoFit();
excelApp.Columns[2].AutoFit();
}
```

Eu consegui desenvolver este código, com base em pesquisas. Porém não sei se se encaixa neste conceito. Será que poderiam me auxiliar com isso?

```
Classe DLL
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace PortalRH.DLL
{
[ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
Guid("00AC4F7E-71B0-4BC7-AD8E-1175CD88457A")]
public class Criptografia : ICriptografia
{
    private string chave = "Exemplo";
    private string texto;
    public Criptografia(){}

    private static readonly byte[] initVectorBytes =    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("tu89geji340t89u2");

    // Esta constante é utilizado para determinar o tamanho da chave do algoritmo de encriptação.
    private const int keysize = 256;

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase)
    {
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null))
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public string Matricula()
    {
        const string matricula = "5444";
        string plaintext = Encrypt(matricula, chave);
        return (plaintext);
    }

    public string Contrato()
    {
        const string contrato = "67334";
        string plaintext = Encrypt(contrato, chave);
        return (plaintext);
    }
}
}
```

Minha interface

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace PortalRH.DLL
{
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
 Guid("37DFD392-8BC3-4A08-B69A-5FDF1B6DF4B1")]
public interface ICriptografia
{

    string Matricula();
    string Contrato();
}
}
```

Comment: Pode colocar esses exemplos na sua pergunta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente seu código está correto, vou compartilhar minha experiência, C# interop com VB6/C# (VS 2012) talvez lhe ajude em alguns detalhes que estão faltando.

1. **Abra o menu propriedades(properties) do seu projeto (DLL) e siga os passos da imagem abaixo para configurar sua DLL.**
   [image: Interop configuração]
2. **Trecho código fonte DLL interop:**

> ```
> [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
> [ProgId("Interop.MeuInteopId")]
> public class MinhaClass: IMinhaClass
> {
>     public string Usuario { get; set; }
>     public void Adicionar(MeuObj obj)
>     {
>          minhalista.Add(obj);            
>     }
> }
>
> public string Pesquisar()
> {
>     return "teste";
> }
> ```

3. **Trecho código Interface**

> ```
> public interface IFarmPop
> {
>     void Adicionar(MeuObj obj)
>     string Usuario { set; get; }
> ```

**Obs:** No meu caso somente os métodos que estão na interfaces são expostos no interop, ou seja, quando utilizar a DLL em outros aplicativos, os mesmos só terão acesso aos métodos que estão na Interface.**

**"Expondo" sua DLL para o mundo!**

Dentro do ambiente de desenvolvimento basta referenciar sua DLL, caso dê tudo certo os métodos expostos estarão acessíveis. Não sei em que linguagem estão as outras aplicações a que se refere na pergunta, porém, o processo é semelhante.

Para que outras aplicações tenham acesso a sua DLL (fora do ambiente de desenvolvimento), é necessário registra-lá com a ferramenta **Regasm**.

> Segundo a Microsoft: **Regasm** é uma ferramenta que permite clientes COM
>   criar classes .NET Framework de forma transparente. Uma vez que uma
>   classe é registrada, qualquer cliente COM pode usá-lo como se a classe
>   fosse uma classe COM.

Pode-se utilizar também instaladores para registrar sua DLL interop,
porém se quiser registrar via linha de comando siga os passos:

1. No prompt de comando navegue para: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\"**versão do framwork**" (versão que você compilou sua DLL)
2. Execute o comando: `regasm.exe SuaDLL.dll /register /codebase /tlb`

Comment: Obrigado, esta informação foi muito útil.