# Usar uma .tlb que possui uma dependencia de dll .net

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6, itextsharp

Desenvolvi uma biblioteca que utiliza como base a `dll` *itextsharp*, no entanto essa biblioteca que escrevi em VB.Net será utilizada em um programa VB6 e portanto é necessário gerar uma `tlb` da mesma.

Fica a duvida, pois apesar de gerar uma `tlb` da minha `lib`, não sei que providencia tomar a respeito da dependência.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47254/com-interop-com-client-e-server/47328#47328 @cleiton-ribeiro

Comment: Todo esse processo eu ja conheço... eu ja tenho a .tlb de minha classe, entretanto ela tem uma dependencia .DLL em c# e nao sei o que fazer com essa dependencia.

Comment: @CleitonRibeiro Já tentou colocar essa DLL em diretórios visíveis pela variável de ambiente `PATH`?

Comment: Será se não está faltando registrar? `regasm.exe SuaDLL.dll /register /codebase /tlb`

Comment: A tlb ja foi registrada... na verdade percebi que o problema eram os parâmetros da classe acessada. Pois o array de strings do vb.net é diferente do array de strings do VB6, mas sei que existe um meio de utilizar tipos do VB.net no vb6. Voces sabem como faze-lo?

Comment: Aí já muda o foco da pergunta, teria que editar e colocar o código tanto em VB quanto C# para facilitar o entendimento. @CleitonRibeiro