# Instanciar dll criada em C# .net para o VB6

Tags: c#, dll, visual-basic-6

Tenho uma dll que quero consumir, desenvolvida em c#, e desejo carregar esta dLL no VB6. Como posso fazer isso? Quais os passos devo seguir?

Dentro do codigo VB6 abaixo já tem uma chamada a esta dll:

```
Dim mail As New MamMail
    Body = Replace(Body, vbCrLf, "</BR>")
    mail.SendMail smtpServer, smtpPort, smtpSsl, userName, Password, fromAddress, toAddress, cc, Subject, Body
    Set mail = Nothing
    Exit Sub
```

Mas quando compilo o no vb6 recebo: `compile error.User defined type not defined`.

Comment: Aqui tem um passo a passo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47254/com-interop-com-client-e-server/47328#47328

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu projeto da `DLL` faça o seguinte:

`Configuration Properties` -> `Build` configure a propriedade `Register for COM interop` com o valor `True`.

E no seu projeto `VB` adicione a referência a Type Library "NomeDaDLL";

[Fonte.](http://comunidade.itlab.com.br/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/985609831/m/188603931)

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

VB6 chamando componentes .Net não é recomendado. Lembre-se que o suporte ao VB6 não existe mais.
Mas se for necessário, você deve exportar sua interface com os comandos próprios para isto. Veja neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29834096/c-sharp-com-interop-class-methods-are-not-visible-in-vb6) mais informações.
Lembre de setar sua dll para x86, pois de outra forma poderá ocorrer erro na carga do módulo em ambiente 64 bits.

Comment: Ok, fou fazer isso sim.  Muito obrigado